# Hyphen in Array keys

Tags: php, arrays

All,

I have an array with hyphens in the key name. How do I extract the value of it in PHP? It returns a 0 to me, if I access like this:

```
print $testarray->test-key;
```

This is how the array looks like

```
 testarray[] = {["test-key"]=2,["hotlink"]=1}
```

Thanks

Comment: The `->` operator isn't meant for accessing array items; it's meant for accessing object members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have problems:

```
testarray[] = {["test-key"]=2,["hotlink"]=1}
    1                        2
```

1. You are missing `$` used to create variables in php
2. It is not a valid array format

.

```
print $testarray->test-key;
               1
```

1. The `=>` operator is used for objects, not arrays, use `[]` instead.

Here is how your code should be like:

```
$testarray = array("test-key" => 2, "hotlink" => 1);
print $testarray['test-key'];
```

Finally,

**[See PHP Array Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)**

Comment: What if I want to access it as an Object?

Comment: You can not access an array as an object

Comment: @Vincent: Why do you want to read it as object in the first place, there is no need, any ways you should first convert array to object as shown here: http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-array-to-object/

Comment: please refer to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925044/hyphens-in-keys-of-object

Comment: @Vincent: It looks to be an object too, if it works for you anyway, you can go for that :)

Answer (score 4):

`print $testarray["test-key"];`

The PHP manual has a good page explaining arrays and how to do things with them:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php