# Hyphens in Keys of Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an stdClass Object like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [key-west] => 1 [disney-land] => 1 )
```

I am trying to retrieve the value like this:

`$objectName->key-west`

but the value returned is 0. Why? and How can I retrieve it as 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
echo $objectName->{'key-west'};
```

Comment: Works great, but an explanation to why would have been useful.  This post provides a good explanation: '[Curly braces in string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/1759873)'.

Comment: Very Very Helpfull Thanks much brother (bow)(bow)(bow)(bow)(bow)(bow)(bow)(bow)