# php object attribute with dot in name

Tags: php, oop, naming-conventions

I have mysql table with collumns like 'operation.date', 'operation.name' and etc.
After fetching that table data as object with `$mysqli->fetch_object()` i get this (print_r of row):

```
stdClass Object
(
[id] => 2
[operation.date] => 2010-12-15
[operation.name] => some_name
)
```

how do I acces `operation.date` and `operation.name` and all other weirdly named object properties?

Comment: This is a duplicate. The answer is, it's not a valid property. You should change it. But you can use `$obj->{'operation.date'}` to access it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hyphens in Keys of Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925044/hyphens-in-keys-of-object) and also [How do I access this object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758449/php-how-do-i-access-this-object-property)

Comment: Sorry for that. Was searching but not for hyphens.

Comment: No problem. Wasnt that easy to find anyway.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Specify aliases in your SQL query like `SELECT column AS nameWithoutDots ...`
or access these properties with `$object->{'operation.name'}`
or cast the object to array like this: `$obj = (array)$obj; echo $obj['operation.name']`.

Comment: +1 for telling the OP how to cure the cause and not the symptoms

Comment: I know about aliases, but too much effort to write miles long query with all the columns as aliases :) Since your answer was most informative I will accept it ;) Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 16):

The correct way of accessing properties with a dot should be :

```
echo $object->{"operation.date"}
```

Answer (score 6):

To access these attributes you need to wrap them with curly brackets:

`echo $object->{"operation.date"} //2010-12-15`

If you set an attribute this way the offending symbol gets removed, allowing you to access the attribute as `echo $object->operationdate //2010-12-15`

Comment: +1 but `operation.date` needs to be wrapped in quotes I think.

Answer (score 2):

Change the sql to return valid property names using the 'as' feature

eg. select operation.date as date

Answer (score 0):

You can get assoc array instead object by using `$mysqli->fetch_assoc()`