# php period in object name

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php object attribute with dot in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351018/php-object-attribute-with-dot-in-name)

I'm dealing with PHP, getting an object returned by a Microsoft web service, and there is a period in the object name!

```
    object(stdClass)#22 (1) {
  ["DAE.Country"]=>
  array(24) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
      ["CountryName"]=>
      string(4) "Asia"
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "27"
    }
}
}
```

How do I access an object in PHP with a period in its name?

```
$response->DAE_GetCountryListResult->DAE.Country;
```

and

```
$response->DAE_GetCountryListResult-['DAE.Country'];
```

both fail. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this syntax to access the property you want:

```
$obj->{'DAE.Country'}
```

You can also use a variable and expressions inside the braces:

```
$prefix = 'DAE';
$name = 'Country';
$another_obj = $obj->{"$prefix.$name"};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351018/php-object-attribute-with-dot-in-name

Comment: @MihaiIorga Good find, voted :)

Comment: Thanks Everybody! Danka Danka Danka!