# How i can doing for call a object with a dot in middle, for example parsing one xml to php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I need parse a response xml in php, and i call the object into object, but one object have a "." or "-" in middle.

For example xml :

```
  [obj1]
     [obj1.1]
            Array(
                  [value]xxxxxx
             .....
```

In php i trying :

```
    $myvalue = $xml->obj1->obj1.1['value'];
    echo $myvalue;
```

And need a function or method or instuction for realize this call to obj1.1.
Thanks, 
PD: sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the element as follows

```
$myvalue = $xml->obj1->{'obj1.1'}['value'];
```

Originally answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351141/3944304