# Laravel 5: How to use array_get method to access an attribute with a dot inside

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have an array like this:

```
$data = [
  "x" => [
    "y" => 5,
    "a.b" => 10
  ]
]
```

I can access `x.y` like this:

```
array_get($data, 'x.y');
```

However, how can I access `x.(a.b)` (sometimes written as `x.a->b`)

I tried the following:

```
array_get($data, 'x.a.b');
array_get($data, 'x.a->b');
```

But neither seems to work.

Comment: why you name it as a.b name it as ab and then you can access it

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with `array_get`. If you take a look at the function (**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:155**):

```
function array_get($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    return Arr::get($array, $key, $default);
}
```

Which calls the get function of the `Arr` class (**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php:278**):

```
public static function get($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (! static::accessible($array)) {
        return value($default);
    }

    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $array;
    }

    if (static::exists($array, $key)) {
        return $array[$key];
    }

    if (strpos($key, '.') === false) {
        return $array[$key] ?? value($default);
    }

    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
        if (static::accessible($array) && static::exists($array, $segment)) {
            $array = $array[$segment];
        } else {
            return value($default);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

If you take a look at the foreach loop which handles the `.`, it does not support the structure your array has.

Answer (score 1):

```
`<?php
$data = [
  "x" => [
    "y" => 5,
    "a.b" => 10
  ]
];
echo $data['x']['a.b'];
// get like this
?>`
```

if you are accessing from db use aliases as mentioned in below link
[php object attribute with dot in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351018/php-object-attribute-with-dot-in-name)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, based on your example:

```
$data = [
  "x" => [
    "y" => 5,
    "a.b" => 10
  ]
];

array_get($data, "x")['a.b'] //gives you the right value
```

You actually don't have to use `array_get` for an array as this though. And also why would you use such a name for your array index.

Comment: SAML does this, sadly

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getNestedArr($array, $key, $default = null)
    {

        if (strpos($key, ',') === false) {
            return $array[$key] ?? value($default);
        }

        foreach (explode(',', $key) as $segment) {
            $array = $array[$segment];
        }

        return $array;
    }
$array = ['GrandParent' => ['parent' => ['childs' => 'xyz']]];
    $data = $this->getNestedArr($array, 'GrandParent,parent,childs');
    print_r($data);
```

Answer is "xyz"

I'm not sure this'll solve your problem, but it's very useful when you get the value from nested array

Comment: Your answer does not match what is asked for in the question, it is suggested to review  your answer