# access value from SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have following XML

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
   [active-until] => 2015-03-16T13:45:32Z
   [billing-first-name] => rriiggiidd
   [billing-last-name] => smith
   [created-at] => 2014-03-16T13:45:32Z
   [customer-id] => 50
   [eligible-for-free-trial] => false
   [email] => rigids.php2@gmail.com
   [expired-at] => SimpleXMLElement Object
       (
           [@attributes] => Array
                 (
                     [type] => datetime
                     [nil] => true
                  )

       )
)
```

I want to fetch value for `customer-id` and `email`
I am using the code as `echo $xml->email;`

It is working for me but when i used same for `customer-id` like `echo $xml->customer-id;`

It didn't worked(may be because it contains (**-**))

Can anyone please suggest how to access value if it has hyphen (-).

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hyphens in Keys of Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925044/hyphens-in-keys-of-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as following for the spaces

```
$object->{'object-property'};
```

So in your case it will be as

```
$xml->{'customer-id'};
```

etc.